# Re-writing this smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, ace, poco-libraries

Im transferring some code from ACE to Poco. I'm new to multithreaded design so it is confusing me just a little!

```
typedef Arc::AutoPtr<ResultSet, ACE_Thread_Mutex> QueryResult;
```

Im not able to just re-write it like this, as Poco::AutoPtr only accepts one argument as a class template

```
typedef Poco::AutoPtr<ResultSet, Poco::Mutex> QueryResult;
```

How should i write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `Arc::AutoPtr` is, because I couldn't find anything like that in the ACE documentation. However if it's the same as `ACE_Refcounted_Auto_Ptr` then the corresponding typedef for Poco would probably be `typedef Poco::SharedPtr<ResultSet> QueryResult;`. But it's not clear from the docs whether the SharedPtr in Poco implements a thread safe reference counting, so you have to be careful of that.

`Poco::AutoPtr` is actually an intrusive smart pointer which requires support from the pointed type (similar to `boost::intrusive_ptr`).

Comment: Poco::SharedPtr does provide thread-safe reference counting. Default ReferenceCounter uses AtomicCounter which provides thread-safety through platform-specific atomic primitives or, if those are not available, FastMutex. User can also provide their reference counter:

template <class C, class RC = ReferenceCounter, class RP = ReleasePolicy<C> >
class SharedPtr { /*...*/ }